# VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have a jar library in my Android project, and I'm started to get a lot of errors while running the app:

```
VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature <...>
Failed resolving Lcom/mad/ad/AdWhirlMadAdapter; interface 835 'Lcom/adwhirl/AdWhirlLayout$AdWhirlInterface;'
Link of class 'Lcom/mad/ad/AdWhirlMadAdapter;' failed
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions, but the solutions are for Eclipse, and I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from adwhirl.com

> Important notice: We will retire AdWhirl on 30 September 2013. Ad
>   network mediation can be managed with AdMob Mediation, a free and
>   robust tool with features like network-level reporting, country-level
>   allocation, and support for more ad formats. Sign up here and follow
>   these steps to import your placements into AdMob.

MADNET no longer supports AdWhirl mediation, please use AdMob mediation.

- The new version of library can be found - [MADNET SDK 5187v](http://tinyurl.com/lbmhk8d).
- User guide - [MADNET SDK Guide 5187v](http://tinyurl.com/karbwok) (you can comment this doc).
- Note the change in the life cycle (in guide) of ad-space.
- Remove from you manifest OpenUDID and MadProvider.

Comment: Hi Andrey, I think the problem is not in the AdWhirl, because it's only 3 lines from a lot of errors, which contains not only AdWhirl. Full log: http://pastebin.com/JpHHX1xx
BTW, MadNet ads work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use proguard to build you application, you shold keep classes of MADNET SDK as public. To do this just add next strings into your proguard-file:

```
-keep public class com.mad.** {
  public protected *;
}
```

Also, if you use AdMob or AdWhirl mediator, add it packages to proguard exclusion too like in example:

```
-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
  public protected *;
}
```

Please, also check xml settings for AdMob mediation

```
<com.mad.ad.AdMobFloatingLayout
     xmlns:mad="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mad.ad"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
     android:id="@+id/adFloatingLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     mad:admobExtraLabel = "mAdtestevent"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"       
     ads:adUnitId="e1a33043e60c4126">

     <ListView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
 </com.mad.ad.AdMobFloatingLayout>
```

here:
**mad:admobExtraLabel** - Label of customEvent, specified on AdMob site
**ads:adSize** - AdSize for Google ads.
**ads:adUnitId** - your mediation id.

Can to skype-call, to accelerate the problem solving?

Comment: I'm using AdStaticView. Yes, you can add me: wia-games